# How Doctrine saves new related objects

Tags: php, orm, doctrine

If I create a new Doctrine object, with lots of relations, should I save() these relations before assigning them to newly created object?
E.g.

```
$main = new Main();
$child = new Child();
$main->child_rel = $child; // do I need to save the child obj explicitly?
$main->save();
```

I assumed that parent will automatically call cascading saves, but this doesn't seem to be the case for a newly instantiated parent object.

How does it really work?

Comment: How are you defining your relationships? It should do it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doctrine take care of everything and save related records if needed.
By the way, you don't need to instanciate an related object. You can use this syntax :

```
$user->Email->address = 'me@server.com';
$user->save();
```

In the case of one-to-many and many-to-many relationships :

```
$user->Phonenumbers[]->phonenumber = '123 123';
$user->Phonenumbers[]->phonenumber = '456 123';
$user->Phonenumbers[]->phonenumber = '123 777';
$user->save();
```

More infos on the [doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/working-with-models.html#dealing-with-relations).